# How can I customize login url for registered users in WordPress multi site for user login?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

i have a multi-site setup where main site is used for my website and 2nd site is used for community forum which is installed on sub-domain.

now when a user confirms his registration, they get sign-in link for my main site instead of my community forum which is on sub-domain.
check this one for example
https://novoapp.com/wp-activate.php?key=abbe9f26a7524009

how can i customize the “login” link for that page to have my sub-domain instead of my main domain.

thanks in advance.